# Redux-saga calls action after cancel

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga

I'm trying to implement React-boilerplate with redux-saga inside. So i'm trying to fetch some data from the server and then make a redirect to another page. The problem is that before redirecting saga makes second request to the server. I guess there is something wrong with cancelling it. Here is a part of my code:

```
export function* fetchData() {
  ...
  console.log('fetched');
  yield browserHistory.push('/another-page');
}

export function* fetchDataWatcher() {
  while (yield take('FETCH_DATA')) {
    yield call(fetchData);
  }
}

export function* fetchDataRootSaga() {
  const fetchWatcher = yield fork(fetchDataWatcher);

  yield take(LOCATION_CHANGE);
  yield cancel(fetchWatcher);
}

export default [
  fetchDataRootSaga
]
```

So in this example i have two console logs, the second one appears before redirecting. How can i fix it?

And another question. Actually, i have more functions in this file. Should i create "rootSaga" for each of them or i can cancel them all in that fetchDataRootSaga()? I mean is it normal if i cancel sagas this way:

```
export function* fetchDataRootSaga() {
  const watcherOne = yield fork(fetchDataOne);
  const watcherTwo = yield fork(fetchDataTwo);
  ...

  yield take(LOCATION_CHANGE);
  yield cancel(watcherOne);
  yield cancel(watcherTwo);
  ...
}
```

Thanks in advance!
P.S. I'm not sure if this code is best practices. It is inspired by [this repository](https://github.com/mxstbr/react-boilerplate)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe start by adjusting your loop inside `fetchDataWatcher` to look a little more like this

```
export function* fetchDataWatcher() {
  while (true) {
    yield take('FETCH_DATA');
    yield call(fetchData);
  }
}
```

Also you can route better by doing something like this perhaps

```
import { push } from 'react-router-redux';
import { put } from 'redux-saga/effects';

export function* fetchData() {
  ...
  console.log('fetched');
  yield put(push('/another-page'));
}
```

Overall I would hesitate to `put` a route change and then altogether separately do a `take` on it, only if you wish to cancel on all location changes (but I assume that's what you're after :) )

Answer (score 0):

This defeats the purpose of saga, which is to handle potentially long running async requests and returns. You could instead set a state in your redux store like so

```
export function* fetchData() {
  ...
  console.log('fetched');
  yield put(setRedirectState('/another-page'));
}
```

Then see if the redirect state is set in your container in ComponentWillUpdate and redirect accordingly to something like this

```
import { push } from 'react-router-redux';
dispatch(push(state.redirecturl))
```

I haven't tried this, but the experience I have with React-boilerplate, this is what I would try first.

Comment: Have you checked that you've not dispatched the action 'FETCH_DATA' twice, which would trigger the saga twice? What happens if you change take() to takeLatest()?